# What is the difference between + and +=?

Tags: python

```
available_items = {"health potion": 10, "cake of the cure": 5, "green elixir": 20, "strength sandwich": 25, "stamina grains": 15, "power stew": 30}
health_points = 20

health_points += available_items.pop("stamina grains", 0)

print(health_points += available_items.pop("stamina grains", 0))  # <-- this does not work, but works with +
```

In the example above, if I use `+=`, I cannot add a `print()` in front of it.

I get an error when I try to add a `print()` to it, but when I change it to `+`, it works with `print()`.

Could someone explain it?

Comment: One is an [augmented assignment *statement*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements), the other is a [binary arithmetic operation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), an *expression*. You can't pass statements as arguments to functions (e.g. you couldn't do `print(return "foo")`, either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not print an operation to a screen. You can print results of operations. For example, if you want to print the result of this operation **(health_points += available_items.pop("stamina grains", 0))** , you have to write **print(health_points)**. Otherwise if you want to write operation as a string for user, you have to write it under quotation marks like that **print("health_points += available_items.pop("stamina grains", 0)")**, or like that **print("health_points"+"=", (available_items.pop("stamina grains", 0)), sep='')**

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C or Java, in Python `+=` is not an operator and can't be used within an expression.

So you can only use it by itself.